# Hilbert transform on a Besov space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, besov-spaces

Consider the usual Hilbert transform of periodic functions
$$H(f) = \frac{1}{2\pi}P.V.\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\cot(\frac{x-y}{2})f(y)dy.$$
We know $H$ does not map $L^\infty$ continuously to $L^\infty$. Now we consider $H$ on the Besov space $B^0_{\infty, \infty}$, which is a little larger than $L^\infty$. Can we say $H$ maps $B^0_{\infty, \infty}$ continuously to $B^0_{\infty, \infty}$? If no, are there any counter-examples?